# Can't deposit from Etherdelta wallet or Metamask to Etherdelta site

Tags: etherdelta

I've tried 2 ways to deposit Eth on Etherdelta site and both failed.  What am I doing wrong?

Way #1 - Moved Eth to my Metamask.  I can see the amount on Etherdelta under wallet.  I click deposit to move from Metamask to Etherdelta.  I get a popup saying sent with a link to check progress.  Click link and it says transaction can't be found.  (it does say if just submitted wait 30 seconds but I've waited hours).  My money still just shows on the Metamask and wallet area.

Way #2 - I disabled Metamask this morning, also switched out of Chrome to Firefox.  I moved more Eth from my Gdax to the Etherdelta wallet on site.  Again this money now shows in my wallet.  Click deposit to move from wallet to site itself and I get the same popup saying sent but then saying transaction can't be found.  This was about 2 hours ago.  My money still just shows on the wallet.

What am I doing wrong??  Thanks.

Comment: i have the same issue too. Heres it my tx. https://etherscan.io/address/0xBc99D8D69cCBf415f5125822685D40301E571EE5

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17759)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17759)

Answer (score 1):

What did you choose as gas price? The "recommended" 4 Gwei must have been too low for the Ethereum network's traffic at the time. Try using **Gas Price SafeLow** from [ethgasstation.info](https://ethgasstation.info) before you do any Ethereum transactions.